# Can dividing code too much make it inefficient?

Tags: python, performance, optimization

If code is divided into too many segments, can this make the program slow?

For example - Creating a separate file for just a single function.

In my case, I'm using Python, and suppose there are two functions that I need in the main.py file. If I placed them in different files (just containing the function).

(Suppose) Also, If I'm using the same library for the two functions and I've divided the functions into separate files.

How can this affect efficiency? (Machine performance-wise and Team-wise).

Comment: Without any language being specified, this is impossible to answer. While there *are* cases where keeping code in one place helps with things like inlining, it's very, very rarely a significant factor in performance - but it can be an important factor in code maintinability.

Comment: Are we talking initial startup time, startup time with bytecode (*.pyc) files already present or runtime? Impact of all of them is different. In my experience all other factors were _much_ more important to performance. I would not worry about it unless you have a very special use case.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I was thinking the same, I asked just to make sure. Also, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the language, the framework you use etc. However, dividing the code too much can make it unreadable, which is (most of the time) the bigger problem. Since most of the time you will (or should) be working in a team, you should consider how readable your code would be for them.

However, answering this in a definite way is difficult. You should ask a Senior developer on your team for guidelines.

Comment: I'd say that dividing the code up too *little* can make it unreadable too - that's what I see more often than the opposite.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you. At the end, it is experience that leads you to find the best way. However, since OP asked about dividing it too much, I thought I would make him aware of this problem.